# Knockout binding and CK Editor toolbar not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, ckeditor

I am totally new to knock-out custom binding, I am trying to integrate ckeditor with knock-out biding, I have the following binding got from Google search,

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.wysiwyg = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var $element = $(element);


            $element.attr('contenteditable', true);
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                var isSubscriberChange = false;
                var isEditorChange = true;
                $element.html(value());
                var isEditorChange = false;

                $element.on('input, change, keyup, mouseup', function () {
                    if (!isSubscriberChange) {
                        isEditorChange = true;
                        value($element.html());
                        isEditorChange = false;
                    }
                });
                value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                    if (!isEditorChange) {
                        isSubscriberChange = true;
                        $element.html(newValue);
                        isSubscriberChange = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the following code to bind,

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("/getdata", function (data) {

            ko.applyBindings({
                testList: [{
                    test: ko.observable()
                },
                {
                    test: ko.observable()
                }]
            }, document.getElementById('htmled'));

    });
});
```

HTML as follows

```
 <div id="htmled" data-bind="foreach:testList">
                 Data
     <div class="editor" data-bind="wysiwyg: test">Edit this data</div>

 </div>
```

The binding works and show the toolbar when I  call the   ko.applyBindings outside the  $.getJSON method. But when I call applyBindings inside, the toolbars not appearing. Can any body help me on this? I must be missing something for sure, any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Jsfiddle Added

Working :http://jsfiddle.net/jogejyothish/h4Lt3/1/
Not Working : http://jsfiddle.net/jogejyothish/Se8yR/2/

Jyothish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is this:

1. Your page loads with the single div. KO has yet to be applied to this div.
2. document.ready() fires. The CKEditor script applied CKEditor to any matching divs (none).
3. You make your ajax call.
4. The Ajax call completes. You apply bindings.
5. KO inserts two new divs, neither of which has CKEditor.

In order to fix it, you need to add some code inside your ajax success function to manually initialise the CKEditors, like:

```
        $(".editor").each(function(idx, el) {
            CKEDITOR.inline(el)
        });
```

Here it is, working in your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Se8yR/5/

The reason your working version works is because the bindings are applied in document.ready, so KO renders the two div elements in time, and the CKEditor is successfully applied to them.

Comment: Thnaks a lot sifriday, really saved my time, and thanks for step by step details,

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor takes some time to load.

In your first example, it loads after ko applies, which works fine.

In the second example, it loads before ko applies. The problem is that CKEditor looks for the `contenteditable` attribute which you set with ko, so the editor is not created.

You can create it manually with:

```
CKEDITOR.inline(element).setData(valueUnwrapped || $element.html());
```

[**Doc**](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Se8yR/3/)